# Network Discovery Command not working in window form application

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I want to 'Turn on Network Discovery' in C# using this code, but it does not work for me
///////////////////

```
public void TOND()
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group = Network Discovery new enable=Yes");

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(objException.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to improve the chance to get an answer, please provide more details on what errors are you given and what's your unexpected output. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"but it does not work for me"* is not a technical description of a problem. I mean, who knows what you mean by that

Comment: Your command does not adhere to what is in help. `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule /?`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wasted our time with non help file stuff,